# why use 32-bit register when the data type is 64-bit?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64, instructions, instruction-set

I was reading a textbook that has an exercise that generates assembly code based on C code:

C code:

```
long arith(long x, long y, long z)
{
   long t1 = x ^ y;
   long t2 = z * 48;
   long t3 = t1 & 0x0F0F0F0F;
   long t4 = t2 - t3;
   return t4;
}
```

Assembly code:

```
//x in %rdi, y in %rsi, z in %rdx
arith:
   xorq %rsi, %rdi               //t1 = x ^ y
   leaq (%rdx,%rdx,2), %rax      //3*z
   salq $4, %rax                 //t2 = 16 * (3*z) = 48*z
   andl $252645135, %edi         //t3 = t1 & 0x0F0F0F0F
   subq %rdi, %rax               //Return t2 - t3
   ret
```

I'm confused with this assembly code:

```
andl $252645135, %edi         //t3 = t1 & 0x0F0F0F0F
```

why we don't use:

```
andq $252645135, %rdi
```

The probmen is, let's say all bits of  `t1` is 1, so for original C code `long t3 = t1 & 0x0F0F0F0F;`, the upper 32 bits of `t3` will be 0s. But if we use `andl` instruction, and only operates on `%edi`, the upper 32 bits of `%rdi` will still be 1s,so this really change the value of `t4` in `long t4 = t2 - t3;` where `t3`'s upper 32 bits are all 1s but they are supposed to be 0s?

Comment: There is an **exception** for 64 bit registers. Accessing the first 32 bits always zeroes out the top 32 bits. I had the same question when I started too :).

Comment: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in Section 3.4.1.1 of the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 1 (Basic Architecture) which states:

> When in 64-bit mode, operand size determines the number of valid bits in the destination general-purpose register:
>
> - 64-bit operands generate a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register.
> - 32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register.
> - 8-bit and 16-bit operands generate an 8-bit or 16-bit result. The upper 56 bits or 48 bits (respectively) of the destination general-purpose register are not modified by the operation. If the result of an 8-bit or 16-bit operation is intended for 64-bit address calculation, explicitly sign-extend the register to the full 64-bits.

See the second bullet.

You can gain some insight as to why this is so by reading: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)